# Why Axios or fetch both do not receive cookies from express session?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, fetch

I have an end point like this :

```
router.post('/auth', async (req, res) => {
    req.session.auth = true
})
```

which makes a new property on session object to true. On *Postman*, I can get the cookie back, no problem. However with Axios or Fetch I do not get any cookies. I wonder why.

This is my cors :

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true , origin: 'https://localhost:5173'}));
```

which has my origin

and this is my axios :

```
axios.post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_HOSTNAME}/auth`, {
  username : userRef.current.value,
  password: passwordRef.current.value, 
},{
  withCredentials : true
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Fetch also :

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/auth', {
  method: 'POST', 
  credentials : 'include',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ 
    username : "admin",
    password : "123"
  })
}).then((response) => console.log(response))
.catch((error) => {
  console.error( error);
})
```

How can I get the cookies from using one of these ways?